# Trying to get styles to register than enque

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I have the following code in my functions.php file with a  call in the header, but nothing is being outputted in the html. There are no stylesheets.

I have tried that add action wp_enque_styles with and without the s (style)

```
<?php
function scripts_and_styles() {
  if (!is_admin()) {
  // normalize
    wp_register_style( 'normal-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/2.1.0/normalize.css', array(), '', 'all' );
  // register main stylesheet
    wp_register_style( 'main-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '', 'all' );

  // enqueue styles and scripts
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-stylesheet' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'normal-stylesheet' );
   }
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_styles', 'scripts_and_styles' ); 
?>
```

Comment: never mind figured out I had to use wp_enque_scripts, why is this?

Comment: So is this question still open or not? And _please_ pay more attention to your question titles. _Trying to …_ is not a good title.

Comment: "*I had to use wp_enque_scripts*" - Because there is no analogous hook, `wp_enqueue_styles` (*yet*).

Comment: it's also worth noting, if you're doing everything in a single action and not conditionally enqueueing things, you don't need to register then enqueue, you can pass all the same arguments to enqueue and skip registering them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function scripts_and_styles() {
  if (!is_admin()) {
  // normalize
    wp_register_style( 'normal-stylesheet', 'http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/2.1.0/normalize.css');
  // register main stylesheet
    wp_register_style( 'main-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '', 'all' );

  // enqueue styles and scripts
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-stylesheet' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'normal-stylesheet' );
   }
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_and_styles' ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct hook.

Currently, WordPress has a hook for enqueueing scripts: `wp_enqueue_scripts`, but *does not have* an analogous hook for enqueueing *stylesheets*, such as `wp_enqueue_styles`.

So, for the time-being, hook your stylesheet-enqueueing callback into **`wp_enqueue_scripts`**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Working Example on how to do it

```
// Create action hook to call the related function
add_action('wp_enque_scripts', 'register_my_style');

// Create the function to be included in the action hook above
function register_my_style() {

// Register your style
wp_register_style('my_css_style', plugins_url('/plugin_directory_name/css/mystyle.css/'));

//enque it after registered
wp_enque_style('my_css_style');
}
```

Please see the reference here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style